# Validate XPath expression in Perl

Tags: perl, xpath

Please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291826/validate-xpath-expression?rq=1) How can we do the same in Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for libxml's `xmlXPathNewContext` in Perl? It's easy, you [search the CPAN for libxml](https://metacpan.org/search?q=libxml), and then [search (grep) the distribution you found for `xmlXPathNewContext`](http://search.cpan.org/grep?release=XML-LibXML-2.0004&string=xmlXPathNewContext). After that you should have found an example to copy/paste or docs to read.

```
$ perl -mXML::LibXML -e'XML::LibXML::XPathExpression->new( q{/foo} )'

$ perl -mXML::LibXML -e'XML::LibXML::XPathExpression->new( q{/foo<} )'
XPath error : Invalid expression
/foo<
     ^

$ perl -mXML::LibXML -e'XML::LibXML::XPathExpression->new( q{/foo[} )'
XPath error : Invalid expression
/foo[
     ^

$ perl -mXML::LibXML -e'XML::LibXML::XPathExpression->new( q{/foo[]} )'
XPath error : Invalid expression
/foo[]
     ^

$ perl -mXML::LibXML -e'XML::LibXML::XPathExpression->new( q{/foo[1]} )'

$
```